# Django deserialize to model instance without saving to DB

Tags: python, django, serialization

I want to serialize an object to Json, then deserialize it as the object, without save it to DB (it's already saved). The reason is that the current state of the model may be different from the state when I serialized it.

This is how I currently serialize the object:

```
ser_obj = serializers.serialize("json", [self.instance])
```

Now, as I understand, in order to deserialize I can do something like:

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj):
    obj.save()
```

But that will save the object to DB, which I don't want to.
I guess I can also do something like:

```
MyModel(field1 = ser_obj['field1'],
        field2 = ser_obj['field2']
       )
```

But it seems wrong. 
So any idea how can I deserialize json object into Django model without saving to DB?

I did notice that if I use the 'save()', I can then use the obj.object to get the object.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you just not call `save()`, if you don't want to save it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually my question was - what should I do instead of 'save()', but now that you're asking it that way - I guess 'pass' should do... what do you think?

Comment: if you 'pass', why do you deserialise it in the first place? Really, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @dirkgroten I just want to get to model out of the ser_obj. As I understand from the documentation I must run with that loop, but what should be the action in each iteration?

Comment: "get to model out of the ser_obj" doesn't mean anything. `obj` is the object you want (an instance of your django model), you can now look at its data, manipulate and do whatever you need to do without saving it (that only happens if you do obj.save()).

Comment: @dirkgroten I may be missing something. If I get it right - for the serialized model to done deserializing - it has to go through all the iterations, right? only at the end the 'obj' contains the model. so what should happen in each iteration?

Comment: No. `obj_list= serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj)` is a list of instances of your model. You can loop through it like you do, or take the first object in the list (`obj_list[0]`). It’s just a python `list`

Comment: @dirkgroten so that's what I don't get, because when I try something like `obj_list= serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj)` it says that 'obj_list' is a of type 'generator'.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialise without saving to the database.

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj):
    do_something_with(obj)
```

This will return **DeserializedObject** instances. You can find more info in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/)

Comment: thanks. That's what I saw in the documentation. The question was - what should be in 'do_something_with' instead of 'save()'

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the DeserializedObject instance that is being returned. You can for example, get field values from a DeserializedObject like `some_field = obj.object.some_field`

Comment: I don't want to get field by field, just want to get the deserialize model (without saving it). If I get it right - I must run through the loop in order to do it. But what should be the action inside each iteration?

Comment: `obj` will contain a DeserializedObject instance. I am not sure why you want to deserialise it if you are not saving it to the DB, but you can do whatever you want with the `obj` since it is deserialised.

Comment: I just realized that in my case, when I try it without the for loop, something like ` obj = serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj)` I can't do anything with 'obj' since it says it's of type generator. That's why I guessed I must use the for loop, and I didn't understand what I should do inside that loop.

Comment: Does it work for list of objects only? what if I want to serialize and deserialize single object?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve a similar problem and found you can access the objects without saving by accessing the .object property:

```
for deserializedobject in serializers.deserialize("json", ser_obj):
    obj = deserializedobject.object
    print(object.field1)
```

Note that if objects accessed in this way have a related field (eg ForeignKey) then that will point to the current database object with that pk even if one has just been deserialised.

ie if A points to B and both A and B are serialised and later deserialised then A will point to B on the database which may have different values than the deserialised.

Essentially you cannot use this approach to freeze a snapshot of a group of related objects and interrogate them at a later date without executing a save().
(as at Django 3.2.3)